# AngularJS Table creation not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datatables

## **2021 EDIT**:

Disclaimer, this question was written when I was brand new to both HTML and JS. If you are here looking for help for an issue, **this may not be helpful** as my code was pretty much a mess. Apologies for the inconvenience. ***The question will stay up as per site guidelines.***

---

## **ORIGINAL POST**

I am attempting to use create a table using angularJS which draws information from a js list of cars to present them in a table. Per the specifications this must be done using Angular, despite the easier ways existing.

My current issue, is that instead of outputting the information, each column displays the formatting code (`{{ car.Model }}` , for example).

My current code is as follows:

```html
<body ng-app="">
<h2>CARS IN THE LOT:</h2>

<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
              Manufacturer
          </td>
          <td>
            Model
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click = "sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Year
              <span ng-show = "!sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            Stock
          </td>
          <td>
            Price
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            Option
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="roll in cars | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchCar">
          <td>{{ car.Manufacturer }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Model }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Year }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Stock }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Price }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Option }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cars.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'price'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchCar   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  //BUTTON
  var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "increment";
    button.addEventListener ("click", incrementStock(0));
  // create the list of cars
  $scope.cars = [
    { Manufacturer: cars[0].Manufacturer, Model: cars[0].Model, Year: cars[0].Year , Stock: cars[0].Stock , Price: cars[0].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[1].Manufacturer, Model: cars[1].Model, Year: cars[1].Year , Stock: cars[1].Stock , Price: cars[1].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[2].Manufacturer, Model: cars[2].Model, Year: cars[2].Year , Stock: cars[2].Stock , Price: cars[2].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[3].Manufacturer, Model: cars[3].Model, Year: cars[3].Year , Stock: cars[3].Stock , Price: cars[3].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[4].Manufacturer, Model: cars[4].Model, Year: cars[4].Year , Stock: cars[4].Stock , Price: cars[4].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[5].Manufacturer, Model: cars[5].Model, Year: cars[5].Year , Stock: cars[5].Stock , Price: cars[5].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[6].Manufacturer, Model: cars[6].Model, Year: cars[6].Year , Stock: cars[6].Stock , Price: cars[6].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[7].Manufacturer, Model: cars[7].Model, Year: cars[7].Year , Stock: cars[7].Stock , Price: cars[7].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[8].Manufacturer, Model: cars[8].Model, Year: cars[8].Year , Stock: cars[8].Stock , Price: cars[8].Stock , Option: button},
    { Manufacturer: cars[9].Manufacturer, Model: cars[9].Model, Year: cars[9].Year , Stock: cars[9].Stock , Price: cars[9].Stock , Option: button}
  ];
  
});

function incrementStock(number){
    alert("function called");
}
```

With cars.js being as follows:

```
var cars = [
    {"manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "model":"Rav4",
    "year":2008,
    "stock":3,
    "price":8500},

    {"manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "model":"Camry",
    "year":2009,
    "stock":2,
    "price":6500},

    {"manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "model":"Tacoma",
    "year":2016,
    "stock":1,
    "price":22000},

    {"manufacturer":"BMW",
    "model":"i3",
    "year":2012,
    "stock":5,
    "price":12000},

    {"manufacturer":"Chevy",
    "model":"Malibu",
    "year":2015,
    "stock":2,
    "price":10000},

    {"manufacturer":"Honda",
    "model":"Accord",
    "year":2013,
    "stock":1,
    "price":9000},

    {"manufacturer":"Hyundai",
    "model":"Elantra",
    "year":2013,
    "stock":2,
    "price":7000},

    {"manufacturer":"Chevy",
    "model":"Cruze",
    "year":2012,
    "stock":2,
    "price":5500},

    {"manufacturer":"Dodge",
    "model":"Charger",
    "year":2013,
    "stock":2,
    "price":16000},

    {"manufacturer":"Ford",
    "model":"Mustang",
    "year":2009,
    "stock":1,
    "price":8000},

]
```

Comment: where is the `car.js`? can you provide a jsfiddle of it? and why not create a function in angular way? there are lots of error in your code that's why it's not working properly

Comment: When the app displays double curly brackets (`{{ }}`), it means the framework failed to load the app, usually because of a JavaScript error. Check the Developer Console for errors.

Comment: Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: When the HTML has two `ng-app` directives, the framework ignores the second `ng-app` directive. [1](https://plnkr.co/edit/o30nfMiBH7s69KyOr09s?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating "roll in cars" but instead using "car" while printing it. Replace it as (ng-repeat = "roll in cars" to ng-repeat = "car in cars"). In original var cars collection you have used small names for property and while assigning it to $scope.cars you are writing initial letter of property in capital (e.g. "Manufacturer: cars[0].**Manufacturer**" it should be "Manufacturer: cars[0].**manufacturer**"). Additionally I have refactored your code to iterate cars in loop and push it to $scope.cars.

```js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

  .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.sortType = 'price'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse = false; // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchCar = ''; // set the default 
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "increment";
    button.addEventListener("click", incrementStock(0));
    
    var cars = [{
        "manufacturer": "Toyota",
        "model": "Rav4",
        "year": 2008,
        "stock": 3,
        "price": 8500
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Toyota",
        "model": "Camry",
        "year": 2009,
        "stock": 2,
        "price": 6500
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Toyota",
        "model": "Tacoma",
        "year": 2016,
        "stock": 1,
        "price": 22000
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "BMW",
        "model": "i3",
        "year": 2012,
        "stock": 5,
        "price": 12000
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Chevy",
        "model": "Malibu",
        "year": 2015,
        "stock": 2,
        "price": 10000
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Honda",
        "model": "Accord",
        "year": 2013,
        "stock": 1,
        "price": 9000
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Hyundai",
        "model": "Elantra",
        "year": 2013,
        "stock": 2,
        "price": 7000
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Chevy",
        "model": "Cruze",
        "year": 2012,
        "stock": 2,
        "price": 5500
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Dodge",
        "model": "Charger",
        "year": 2013,
        "stock": 2,
        "price": 16000
      },

      {
        "manufacturer": "Ford",
        "model": "Mustang",
        "year": 2009,
        "stock": 1,
        "price": 8000
      },
    ];
    // create the list of cars
    $scope.cars = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      var carObj = {
        Manufacturer: cars[i].manufacturer,
        Model: cars[i].model,
        Year: cars[i].year,
        Stock: cars[i].stock,
        Price: cars[i].price,
        Option: button
      }
      $scope.cars.push(carObj);
    }
  });
function incrementStock(number) {
  alert("function called");
}
```

```css
body{background-color: #95b8cf;}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sortApp">
  <h2>CARS IN THE LOT:</h2>

  <div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Manufacturer
          </td>
          <td>
            Model
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Year
              <span ng-show = "!sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            Stock
          </td>
          <td>
            Price
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            Option
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchCar">
          <td>{{ car.Manufacturer }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Model }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Year }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Stock }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Price }}</td>
          <td>{{ car.Option }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @Rsk22 if this answers your query, then please accept and vote it.